# simplifying mysql query with joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on some other developers code and need to simplify this query which is in the format below.

```
SELECT
    table1.id, table2.userid, table4.groupid
FROM 
    table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE
    userid = table4_userid
and 
    table2.id = table3.table2_id 
and 
    table1.table3_id = table3.id 
and 
    table3.statement_id = 264803 
order by table4_groupid
```

But I am used to join queries by explicitly mentioning the join type i.e. LEFT, RIGHT OR OUTER join. I also use TableName.TableField so that I know which field is from which table. However, as you can see above it's a bit of mix of tablename.tablefield and just tablefield. The above query is working fine but I need to make table4 as a LEFT JOIN so that if there aren't any matching rows in table4 it should still show some data.

My questions are:

1) What types of joins are above?

2) How do I change the above query to make table4 as a LEFT JOIN?

I know you may want the original query but I need just little pointers towards right direction and I will do the rest myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the tables directly in the where statement, it will be considered ordinary `INNER JOIN`s. Using the where statement for joining table are the old way of joining and much harder to read. If you would like to `LEFT JOIN table4`, I suggest that you to rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT
    table1.id, 
    table2.userid, 
    table4.groupid
FROM 
    table1
    JOIN table3
        ON table1.table3_id = table3.id  
    JOIN table2
        ON table2.id = table3.table2_id
    LEFT JOIN table4
        ON table2.userid = table4_userid
WHERE
    table3.statement_id = 264803 
order by 
    table4_groupid
```

Comment: you have a typo `,` after `table1` in the query and after `table3.table2_id`

Comment: np, there's still the one after `table1` `FROM table1,` I removed it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the conditions after the `WHERE` all the above are inner joins.

Try this one, I am not sure of the `ON`s as we don't really know the tables' structures:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t2.userid, COALESCE(t4.groupid, 0)
FROM 
    table1 t1 INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.table3_id=t3.id
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id=t3.table2_id
    LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.userid=t4.table4_userid
WHERE
    t3.statement_id = 264803 
order by t4.groupid
```